# How to add Articles into an Article-based dissertation

Tags: formatting, pdfpages, scrbook

I am writing my dissertation, and recently the university allowed Article-based dissertations instead of classical monographs. So I took this option!

I have the main document where I have a Chap 1: Introduction, Chap 2: Background, and Chap 3: Literature Review.

Now comes the part where I have to attach the Articles (in the main body of the dissertation, not as appendices), Chap 4: Contributions, with the Papers added as sections, that is: Section 1: Paper 1, Section 2: Paper 2...

For this part, there are a couple of options I have in mind, but since I am relatively new to LaTeX, I want to check if there is a better option out there:

1. I can simply copy the same content from the articles and paste it into a tex file to later incorporate it into the main file. (+) I think it is the easiest way. It keeps the whole formatting of the main document for sections, font type, and colours. Links for references work. (-) I do not like it, I would prefer to see the paper as published: two columns, following the journal format.
2. I can use the package `\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}` and incorporate each paper as published. (+) I like the column-formatting of the papers, the paper follows the formatting from the journal, conference. (-) The font type from the pdf does not match the main document font. The links in the included pdf do not work. Sections and the first page of the Papers are on different pages. Two numbers for those pages in the final pdf document.
   [image]
   [image]
3. No idea. Any other suggestions?

Is there a way that I can include the Paper directly using the document class from the Journal? Something like calling the project instead of the tex file?

Comment: There might be a copyright issue: most journals allow using the *content* of a published paper in a PhD thesis, but I'm not sure the permission extends to the literal pdf. You'll have to read carefully the publisher's copyright agreement. That's why I opted for your 1st solution.

Comment: @campa, Thanks for your comment; very valid for this situation. In my case, If I understand the Copyright form, I am entitled to do so: `The right to post and maintain at any time your Author's Original Manuscript (AOM), i.e., the unpublished version of the article created by you prior to peer review; the AM; and the article in its published form as supplied by us as a digital print on your own website for personal or professional use, or in your institution's network or intranet or website, or in a subject repository or network, with the acknowledgement:  The Version of Record of this..`

Comment: I am not a lawyer but it seems to me that that the Copyright form gives you permission to distribute your work as published but not to change it. As I understand it changing fonts would be a no-no.